# How to fix a circular dependency for imports

Tags: python, import, python-3.x, circular-dependency

I have three files:

testimports module:

```
#import moduleTwo
import moduleOne

hiString = "Hi!"

moduleOne.sayHi()
```

moduleOne:

```
import moduleTwo

class sayHi():
    moduleTwo.printHi()
```

moduleTwo:

```
import testimports

def printHi():
    print(testimports.hiString)
```

If I run `testimports`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..file path snipped../testimports/src/testimports.py", line 2, in <module>
    import moduleOne
  File "..file path snipped../testimports/src/moduleOne.py", line 1, in <module>
    import moduleTwo
  File "..file path snipped../testimports/src/moduleTwo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import testimports
  File "..file path snipped../testimports/src/testimports.py", line 6, in <module>
    moduleOne.sayHi()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sayHi'
```

If, however, I uncomment the `import moduleTwo` line in `testimports`, the program gets to this point before it stops working:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..file path snipped../testimports/src/testimports.py", line 1, in <module>
    import moduleTwo
  File "..file path snipped../testimports/src/moduleTwo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import testimports
  File "..file path snipped../testimports/src/testimports.py", line 2, in <module>
    import moduleOne
  File "..file path snipped../testimports/src/moduleOne.py", line 3, in <module>
    class sayHi():
  File "..file path snipped../testimports/src/moduleOne.py", line 4, in sayHi
    moduleTwo.printHi()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'printHi'
```

How would I go about resolving this circular dependency problem?

Comment: Please search SO for circular import.  There are hundreds of questions just like yours.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+circular+import

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Cyclic imports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/python-cyclic-imports)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting `testimports.py` may help:

```
import moduleOne

hiString = "Hi!"

def main ():
    moduleOne.sayHi()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main ()
```

Answer (score 9):

verisimilidude is along the right direction. I would expand a little to give more details.

In both cases, this is what happens:

1. `testimports` is executed as `__main__`
2. `testimports` imports `moduleOne`. Now `moduleOne` is read from file and added to the list of imported modules `sys.modules`.
3. The execution of importing of `moduleOne` starts by importing `moduleTwo`. Now `moduleTwo` is read from file and added to the list of imported modules `sys.modules`. Note at this stage the rest of `moduleOne` hasn't been executed yet so `sayHi` is not defined.
4. Now `moduleTwo` starts execution by importing `testimports`. This is the first time `testimports` is imported and it has nothing to do with it being the same as `__main__`. It is now inserted into `sys.modules`.
5. Here is where things get interesting. The newly imported `testimports` imports `moduleOne`. *But `moduleOne` is already in `sys.modules`*, so it is not read again. Then the execution progresses to the line `moduleOne.sayHi()`. *But the importing of `moduleOne` hasn't finished and `sayHi` is not yet defined*. Hence we get the error.

A similar loop happens if `moduleTwo` is uncommented. In essence, `__main__` imports `moduleTwo` which imports `testimports` which passes the import of `moduleTwo` which is already imported and imports `moduleOne`; which in turn imports `moduleTwo` and then tries to call `moduleTwo.printHi` which isn't defined yet because `moduleTwo` hasn't finished execution all this time.

Anatoly Rr's solution breaks all this by making the module `testimports` not call any other module functionality when imported. So when it is imported by `moduleTwo` it doesn't call `moduleOne.sayHi`. Only when started as `__main__` will it execute that so that execution is delayed after all the imports.

The moral of the story? [Avoid circular dependencies in Python if possible](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that when Python imports something it executes all statements at the base level.  hiString is assigned to again and the call is made again when Module3 imports your original testimports.py as a module.  Anatoly Rr's solution works because the call is now inside a def.  The def is not called because the `__name__` indicates to the Python runtime that the module is being imported. When it is being called from the command line it's module name would be `__main__`.

Comment: Not actually accurate. For example, hiString is not assigned again but there will be two hiStrings. And in both cases there will be a _\_main_\_ in addition to the imported testimports. See my answer for details.