# Append items to list in another file - Python

Tags: python, list, function, file-handling

I'm trying to append inputs to a list in another python file. I think I have the order correct but the error message I get is `AttributeError: module 'inventory' has no attribute 'pick'` when I try it out.

main.py:

```
import inventory

choice = input("--> ")

if "inv pick" in choice:
    inventory.pick()
```

inventory.py:

```
import main

backpack = []

def pick():
    """
    Function for picking up things
    """
    backpack.append(main.choice)
    print(backpack)
```

If I make write the string "inv pick flower" end hit enter I get the error message instead of the printed content of the list 'Backpack'. Maybe I should use .extend instead of .append but neither of it works right now.
Any pointers perhaps?

Regards

Comment: I think your problem is described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python

Comment: @MichaelButscher So they can't import each other? Then I have to use a third .py-file to somehow store and process?

Comment: Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739654/how-to-fix-a-circular-dependency-for-imports) there's a fix.

Comment: @IrfanuddinShafi It worked insofar as there are no error messages but nothing gets printed though...

Comment: Why don't you use the choice as a parameter for `pick()`? As it is, it's bad design.

Comment: Generally you will not want to import `main` anywhere as that will re-run `main.py`. Instead, pass data as parameters from main to the functions in the other modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a much better way to implement what you're trying to achieve without any problematic circular imports.

main.py:

```
import inventory

choice = input("--> ")


inventory.pick(choice)
```

inventory.py:

```
backpack = []

def pick(choice):

    backpack.append(choice)
    print(backpack)
```